# JavaScript DOM change background color not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JavaScript index</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<input name="colorButton" type="button" value="Change background color" />

<script>
"use strict";

function setBGColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

document.colorButton.onclick = setBGColor;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am trying to change the background color of the body once the button is pressed. But I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property called `colorButton` for document:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="colorButton"]').onclick = setBGColor;
```

You need to get the `input` element (since you have name use the element name).

---

Or add an id:

```
<input name="colorButton" id="colorButton" type="button" value="Change background color" />
```

And then:

```
document.getElementById('colorButton').onclick = setBGColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Say like bellow to get the button

```
document.getElementsByName('colorButton')[0].onclick = setBGColor;
```

instead of

```
document.colorButton.onclick = setBGColor;
```